# Why does Paul have to get his medical practice license from a state other than his own?

Tags: downsizing-2017

In Sci-fi *Downsizing (2018)*, Dusan reacted when Paul fixing maid's leg:

> Dusan: You can do this, but you work shit job answering phones?
>
> Paul: When I moved down here, I didn't think I'd be working, so I let
>   my license expire, and **now I'd have to get it in a whole other state**.

Why does he have to get his medical practice license from a state other than his own?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Paul moved from Omaha, Nebraska to Leisureland, New Mexico. Even if he was full sized and working with full sized patients, he would need a new license to formally practice in NM due to differences with how the law works between states. Getting a new license in a different state is much harder than renewing an existing license.

(In other words, this has nothing to do with the science fiction in the movie and everything to do with the real world.)

An [American Medical Association article](https://www.ama-assn.org/practice-management/digital/cross-state-licensing-process-now-live-8-states) from 2017 explains this problem in a bit more depth and describes an attempt to remediate it — but this did not include NM and therefore wouldn’t have helped Paul.